# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bucket')

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to copy this tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@srobtweets/adding-computer-vision-to-your-ios-app-66d6f540cdd2) in which I upload an image from my iOS app to Firebase storage, then Firebase functions detects this and runs web detection using Vision API, then sends response to Firestore database. Since the author did not send their complete `index.js` file, another user uploaded their own [here](https://gist.github.com/joaobiriba/aa1b0d20ce1d3cfa614fb8f2e9275067), but since it was from 5 years ago I tried fixing it.

Here is my index.js file:

```
const Vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
const vision = new Vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.callVision = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(event => {
    const object = event.data;
    const fileBucket = object.bucket;
    const filePath = object.name;
    const gcsPath = `gs://${fileBucket}/${filePath}`;


    // Prepare the request object
    var req = {
      image: {source: {imageUri: gcsPath}},
      features: [{ type: Vision.v1.types.Feature.Type.WEB_DETECTION },
      { type: Vision.v1.types.Feature.Type.SAFE_SEARCH_DETECTION }],
    };
    console.log('vision api image ' + gcsPath);
    // Call the Vision API's web detection and safe search detection endpoints
    return vision.annotateImage(req).then(response => {
        let webDetection = response[0].webDetection;
        let safeSearch = response[0].safeSearchAnnotation;
        return {web: webDetection, safe: safeSearch};
    }).then((visionResp) => {
        var db = admin.firestore();
        let imageRef = db.collection('images').doc(filePath.slice(7));
        return imageRef.set(visionResp);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('vision api error', err);
    });

});
```

Here is my swift code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFunctions
import Firebase


class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    private let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
    private let firestore = Firestore.firestore()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        present(picker, animated: true)
    }
    
    func retrieveAPIData() {
        print("retrieve API called")
        let imageRef = storage.child("images/\(UUID().uuidString).png")
        self.firestore.collection("images").document(imageRef.name)
            .addSnapshotListener { DocumentSnapshot, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }
                else {
                    print(DocumentSnapshot?.data())
                }
        }
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        guard let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage else {
            return
        }
        guard let imageData = image.pngData() else {
            return
        }
        let imageRef = storage.child("images/file.png")
        imageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: {_, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            else {
                self.retrieveAPIData()
            }
        })
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

The issue is, when I run the code, although the image is sent to firebase storage, nothing is being sent to the Firestore database. Here is my database and storage screenshot:
[image: storage]

[image: firestore database]

Here are my logs:

```
9:30:16.063 PM
callVision
Function execution started 

9:30:16.069 PM
callVision
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bucket')

9:30:16.069 PM
callVision
     at /workspace/index.js:9:31 

9:30:16.069 PM
callVision
     at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:78:23) 

9:30:16.069 PM
callVision
     at /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/function_wrappers.js:144:25 

9:30:16.069 PM
callVision
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

9:30:16.069 PM
callVision
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bucket') 

9:30:16.069 PM
callVision
     at /workspace/index.js:9:31 

9:30:16.069 PM
callVision
     at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:78:23) 

9:30:16.069 PM
callVision
at /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/function_wrappers.js:144:25

9:30:16.069 PM
callVision
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

9:30:16.070 PM
outlined_flag   
callVision
 Function execution took 7 ms, finished with status: 'error'
```

and here are my versions:

```
"@google-cloud/vision": "^2.4.2",
"firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
"firebase-functions": "^3.18.0"
```

Comment: The problem comes from this `const fileBucket = object.bucket;`, can you make sure that `object` has a `bucket` property?